# Don't understand why getting a syntax error related to elif

Tags: python-3.x, function

I don't understand why I am getting a syntax error un the elif for this function.

I tried nesting the elif and else statement under the if statement but that did not work either.

```
def largest_number(numberone,numbertwo):
    if numberone > numbertwo:
        return print("{} is the bigger number!".format(numberone)
    elif numberone < numbertwo:
        return print("{} is the bigger number!".format(numbertwo)
    else numberone == numbertwo:
        return print("they are equal!")
```

Error result I am getting:

```
File "<ipython-input-18-7b5c4a40de84>", line 4
elif numberone < numbertwo:
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Close the parentheses for the `print` statement above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is not caused by the `elif` statement. Look at the code immediately above the reported error:

```py
return print("{} is the bigger number!".format(numberone)
```

You're missing a closing parenthesis. the same at line 5:

```py
return print("{} is the bigger number!".format(numbertwo)
```

The `^` symbol does not necessarily point to your error in the Python traceback - it shows you the furthest point that the Python interpreter was able to get to before it encountered your error, and threw the exception.

Comment: For sure! Just believe I did it, let me know if not. Am new to this world :)

Comment: Well done:), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get to know SO and the community. Keep going!